# SVG <image> elements not displaying on Firefox, Safari, iOS

Tags: firefox, d3.js, svg, safari

I've been reading around about this problem. Based on other answers I've seen here, and old bug reports for firefox, I've tried a few different solutions, but none of have worked.

The site is https://www.battlepac.com and in Chrome on desktop the d3 generated horizontal bar chart displays the images on the axis as expected, but not in any other browsers and not on iOS.

The code snippet that generates the images for the axis is:

```
svg.selectAll("image")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("image")
    .attr("class", "bar_image")
    .attr("y", function(d) {
            return yScale(d.candidate)+yScale.bandwidth()/2 - 14;
        })
    .attr("x", "0")
    .attr('href', function(d){
            var img_path = "https://www.battlepac.com/static/images/candidate_images/"+d.candidate+".png";
            console.log(d.candidate);
            return img_path;
        })
    .attr("length", "28px")
    .attr("width", "28px");
```

So it's just appending these images to an already existing SVG -- oddly, the rest of the SVG displays fine (all the rects and labels etc...)

Additionally. the images will show up else where when needed in the Flask templates. It's just in the SVG  elements on non-desktop Chrome that don't work.

I've tried moving from 'xlink:href' attributes to just 'href' and using the full path to the image rather than the local path, but neither of these have worked.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I can get these images to show up?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `.attr("height", "28px")`

Firefox requires both image sizes.

`iOS`, `Safary` requires - `xlink:href`

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. Some times the simplest answers are the hardest to find.

Comment: @Tyler Wood It happens to everyone and I am no exception. :-)